Year, month, day, hours, minutes to Date without "magic"
Let's get this over with.
How do you convert a LocalDateTime to a java.util.Date without any "magic tricks" pulled by Java (which are becoming less and less amusing to me)?
The year, month, and day are correct (January 1, 1900), but the time is for some reason 0:29:43 (instead of 00:00:00, as I intended).
Your time, I figure, may be different, for example because it may depend on time zone.
import java.util.Date;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;

public class DateDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = toDate(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0); // must be: January 1, 1900. 00:00:00
        System.out.println(ZoneId.systemDefault()); // Europe/Moscow
        System.out.println(date); // actual: Mon Jan 01 00:29:43 MSK 1900
    }

    static Date toDate(int year, int month, int day, int hours, int minutes) {
        // LocalDateTime appeared a convenient medium, what with its handy factory methods
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(year, month, day, hours, minutes);
        Instant instant = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
        return Date.from(instant);
    }
}

If for some reason it's impossible, you may change LocalDateTime to some other class from java.util.time. The point is I have year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds and need to make a Date instance from that concisely and readably (preferably, without using any deprecated API). LocalDateTime factory methods appeared handy.
This works but has one deprecated call (should be zero), generates two warnings in total and is ugly AF. Thus suboptimal.
new Date(localDateTime.getYear() - 1900, localDateTime.getMonth().getValue(), localDateTime.getDayOfMonth(), localDateTime.getHour(), localDateTime.getMinute(), localDateTime.getSecond())

I have to use java.util.Date. We got a legacy project. Our APIs expect Date instances.
I examined these before posting (some of them suggest the same, non-working, solution): 1, 2, 3, 4.
Java 8

Why do you want to use the legacy Date library? It's a very bad idea to use it in 2024+.

Please explain the context. What you shared probably won't work unless the JVM is configured to use UTC as the default timezone. I reckon the problem you have is that something is using a LocalDateTime when it should use a ZonedDateTime (with UTC), or an epoch timestamp.

@YoucefLAIDANI I have to. We got a legacy project. Our APIs expect Date instances

As explained in 3 and 4, Date is like Instant. The instant represented by the Date you got is the same as the instant represented by localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant() . It's just that its toString method (or most of the other formatting methods in the legacy API) does not format it correctly.

In other words, if you only use getTime() on the Date and not treat it as a year-month-day-hour-minute-second tuple, you should get correct results.

You can get a Date with the same components by using Calendar, but it will not represent the same instant. Do you want to proceed with that?

Real bad to use java.util.Date but hack: new java.util.Date(localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toInstant().toEpochMilli());

@g00se unfortunately, it still produces unexpected time for me

Example is incomplete because it omits output.  Your issue could be in how it is rendered.
Consider debugging/printing each step to see where the translation breaks down from expectations.
The only part of your code that is going to be distinct to you versus someone else running it is what your ZoneId is because you are using the system default.  Instead, specify a ZoneId that has a 0 offset (e.g. GMT, GMT0, Zulu).

You can return: new Date( year, month , day , hours , minutes, 0 );, you must remember that the months are numbered from “0”.

The Date class had some time zone sensitive bugs with dates around year 1900. I bet you have run into one of those. Can‘t fix it for you. :-( Which is your default time zone?

I too am asking for context. For which purpose do you need to represent a date and time in 1900 and can‘t tolerate an inaccuracy of half an hour?

(@Marce) don't forget that year is 1900 based, that is, argument 0 is interpreted as 1900 (but author wants "without using any deprecated API", which is kind of strange since using Date [not deprecated, I know, but replaced 10 years ago])

BTW posted code is not the real one - it should not compile (without error, in Java)

@usuario85421, I understand that the date with year “1900” is for illustrative purposes only... but good point!!!.

BTW2 the java.time classes use a different calendar then the Date and Calendar classes (minimal/no impact on actual dates, greater impact on older dates), but I believe the problem is probably related to the used time zone -- but we cannot see how you got that "the time is for some reason 0:29:43" (I get 00:00:00 / default time zone)

Also newer versions of the time zone database bundled with Java comes without reliable time zone information for dates before some 1970, which could easily be another hindrance to getting what you want.

"I have year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds and need to make a Date instance" and what time zone is the time given? How is the date being evaluated - printed, saved in database, ... - that is, how you got the 0:29:43? And what is the default TimeZone (ZoneId)?

The time zone database of your JVM seems to be outdated. Your output can not be reproduced. Check this output on a JVM running at GMT (which has +00:00 time zone offset). If you execute this code on a JVM at a non-zero time zone offset, the Date#toString method will reflect that offset in the output. There is no time zone which has an offset of 29 minutes 43 seconds. I have voted to close this question because your issue is not reproducible and you have not provided enough information.

Add this to your code: System.out.println( ZoneId.systemDefault() ) ;. Edit your Question to post the result.

What you're thinking of as an error, probably isn't one. Look at your Instant's timezone offset when shown as ZDT in your zone: 1900-01-01T00:00+02:30:17[Europe/Moscow]

@ArvindKumarAvinash “There is no time zone which has an offset of 29 minutes 43 seconds” today but the OP processes a date at 1900 and by that time there was

@Holger - The OP has added the time zone information to the question now. However, in 1900, Moscow had a time zone offset of +02:30:17, which means LocalDateTime.of(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0).atOffset(ZoneOffset.of("+02:30:17")).withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC) would be 1899-12-31T21:29:43Z which is different from the date-time in the question.

I have reproduced. The OP‘s code converts to a ZonedDateTime of 1900-01-01T00:00+02:30:17[Europe/Moscow], then to an Instant of 1899-12-31T21:29:43Z and finally to an old-fashioned Date that in Europe/Moscow time zone prints as Mon Jan 01 00:29:43 MSK 1900, which disagrees with the starting point.

Funnily trying to construct the Date through the obsolete GregorianCalendar class I get a different wrong output, Mon Jan 01 00:00:33 MSK 1900.

What you are seeing is a bug in the toString method of the antiquated Date class. It manifests for Date values all the way from 1880 up to New Year 1900 GMT (Jan 1, 1900, 2:30:17 MSK). The Date object holds the correct time, it just prints wrong. Can you live with not going further back as, say, Mon Jan 01 03:00:00 MSK 1900?

The Date object holds the correct time, it just prints wrong That's often the way with that class ;)

@ArvindKumarAvinash it’s not different. The OP used the toString() method of Date which shows the time in today’s time zone of Moscow, i.e. +3:00, due to their Locale.

@Holger That doesn‘t explain why it works for 3 in the morning on that day and not for midnight (00:00). Those two times have the same GMT offset in Moscow (+02:30:17). I stand by calling it a bug. And I don‘t expect that bug fixed, ever.

@Anonymous I’m fine with calling it a bug. I only pointed out that the behavior is reproducible and does not come out of thin air. Using today’s offset +3:00 explains the numbers but that does not imply that Date’s toString() method should use that offset.

The date you get that prints wrong, Mon Jan 01 00:29:43 MSK 1900, what happens if you pass it to your legacy code anyway? I am thinking that since the value inside the Date is correct, it might work the way it should?

Indeed, yes. And if you reflect on the fact that Date is essentially a view of a long model and notice that long value from the java.time classes used to instantiate Date doesn't get altered when you retrieve it directly (getTime()) then it makes for confidence

tl;dr

the time is for some reason 0:29:43

Your result is unreproducible. See your code run at Ideone.com. Result: Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 1900. Your JVM’s current default time zone may produce other results, but you neglected to post that time zone. Run: System.out.println( ZoneId.systemDefault() ) ;.
Read on for a better approach in getting to a java.util.Date from a LocalDateTime object. Time zone is crucial.
java.util.Date                           // Legacy class. Terribly designed; use only if you must. 
.from (                                  // New conversion method added to the old class. 
    LocalDateTime                        // Represents a date with time-of-day but lacking the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. 
    .of (
        LocalDate.of ( y , m , d ) ,     // Date-only. 
        LocalTime.of ( h , m , s )       // Time-only. 
    )                                    // Returns a `LocalDateTime` object. 
    .atZone ( 
        ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" )  // Returns a time zone, a `ZoneId` object. 
    )                                    // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object. 
    .toInstant()                         // Returns a `Instant` object. 
)

For example, using an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds:
String output =
        java.util.Date
                .from (
                        LocalDateTime
                                .of (
                                        LocalDate.of ( 1900 , 1 , 1 ) ,
                                        LocalTime.MIDNIGHT
                                )
                                .atZone (
                                       ZoneOffset.UTC
                                )
                                .toInstant ( )
                )
                .toString ( );  // This method lies to you! The JVM’s current default time zone is dynamically applied, while the object actually represents a moment as seen with an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. Very confusing anti-feature.

System.out.println ( "output = " + output );

When run on a JVM with a default time zone of UTC (offset of zero):

output = Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 UTC 1900

For fun, in that code above change that time zone from ZoneOffset.UTC to ZoneId.of ( "Asia/Tokyo" ):

output = Sun Dec 31 15:00:00 UTC 1899

Time Zone
The source of your confusion is time zone, on two counts.
Count # 1 — Determine a moment
The legacy class java.util.Date represents a moment, a specific point on the timeline. A moment is made up of a date, a time of day, and a time zone.

Moment = Date + Time + Zone

For any given moment, the time and the date both vary around the globe by time zone. Noon on January 23 of 2025 in Tokyo Japan is hours earlier than noon in Toulouse France, which is hours earlier than Toledo Ohio US. In this example, we have three different moments, several hours apart.
If you have a date and a time in hand, and want to determine a moment, you need to know in which time zone is that date and time meant to be seen.
If you do not know the intended time zone, then you have reached an impasse and cannot continue. You absolutely cannot guess which zone, you need to know with certainty. And absolutely should not pick a zone randomly as your code is doing with a call to ZoneId.systemDefault which accesses the JVM’s current default time zone. That default can be changed at any moment by any code in any app within that JVM.
If you know the intended zone, then proceed. A real time zone is named in format of Continent/Region, not 2-4 letter codes like CST or IST.
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;

Apply that zone to your LocalDateTime object to determine a moment, a point on the timeline. The LocalDateTime object has two parts: date and time. Adding the third part, time zone, makes a moment. In Java we represent this moment as a ZonedDateTime object.
ZonedDateTime zdt = myLocalDateTime.atZone( z ) ;  // Voilà, a moment. 

We can adjust that moment to be seen from an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC by extracting an Instant. Same moment, different wall-clock/calendar.
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;

Convert from that modern class to its legacy counterpart, java.util.Date.
java.util.Date myJavaUtilDate = java.util.Date.from( instant ) ;

Count # 2 — Date#toString lies
Also very confusing is the fact that java.util.Date#toString lies to you. In generating its text, the method dynamically applies the JVM‘s current default time zone. The result is not the semantics of what is stored within the Date object.
The stored value is a moment as seen in UTC, not as seen in the JVM’s current default time zone.
This lie is a well-intentioned feature (anti-feature?) but terribly poor design choice. This is but one of many reasons to avoid the legacy date-time classes. Always do your work in java.time, then use the new conversion methods added to the old legacy classes as needed to interface with the parts of your own code not yet updated to java.time.
Converting java.util.Date to Instant
To examine a java.util.Date object, you can switch back to java.time. With the java.time.Instant class, your can generate text in standard ISO 8601 format.
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
String output = instant.toString() ;  // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format. 


2024-11-26T16:18:22.123456Z

The Z on the end is a standard abbreviation for an offset of zero, +00:00.
Note the fractional second. The legacy class java.util.Date is limited to mere milliseconds resolution. In contrast, the modern java.time.Instant class resolves to nanoseconds. So calling java.util.Date#from( instant ) may involve data-loss, truncating any microseconds and nanoseconds.
Count from epoch reference
Another way to verify the value of a java.util.Date is to extract its count-from-epoch. Both java.util.Date & java.time.Instant are built on a count from the same epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00Z. The java.util.Date holds a count of milliseconds, while java.time.Instant holds a count of whole seconds plus a number of nanoseconds.
long millisecondsOfJavaUtilDate = myJavaUtilDate.getTime() ;
long millisecondsOfInstant = instant.toEpochMilli() ;

Again, be aware that the Instant object may hold microseconds or nanoseconds. Calling Instant#toEpochMilli() ignores that info.

Since the OP has provided the actual timezone in the meanwhile, i.e. Europe/Moscow, their results are suddenly plausible. As e.g. wikipedia shows, the Moscow time at 1990 was UTC+02:30:17 and Java correctly reflects that, e.g. System.out.println( ZoneId.of("Europe/Moscow").getRules() .getOffset(LocalDateTime.of(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0)) ); prints +02:30:17

A solution (aka hack) is to get the different components of the LocalDateTime and plug them into a Date object. It might work or not depending on your needs.
    public static Date convertToDate(LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
        int year = localDateTime.getYear();
        int month = localDateTime.getMonthValue();
        int day = localDateTime.getDayOfMonth();
        int hour = localDateTime.getHour();
        int minute = localDateTime.getMinute();
        int second = localDateTime.getSecond();

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Date date = new Date(year - 1900, month - 1, day, hour, minute, second);
        
        return date;
    }

Bear in mind this returns a different point in time compared to the original LocalDateTime, but it sounds from your question that's what you want.
And caveat emptor: please add plenty of tests for whatever you are doing, including when there are daylight savings changes.

Thanks, but I don't want to use deprecated methods

I would use the Calendar API and set each of the fields, instead of using the deprecated Date constructor.

@Sweeper Calendar handles zero days in a creative way, I don't like it

@Cagepi What are "zero days"? Days of the month start from 1. Calendar is the designated way to work with date components (as opposed to instants) since the components-related methods in Date are deprecated, and until java.time was introduced, of course.

@Cagepi -- no deprecated methods, no Calendar, but still sticking to Date... kind of curious (impossible?) requirement -- javadoc of Date": "As of JDK 1.1, the Calendar class should be used to convert between dates and time fields ..." (more than 25 years ago)
